# php - how can I fix this illegal offset type

Tags: php

I'm getting an error saying that I have an illegal offset in this code:

```
function _generate_users($ceny, $komu, $ile, $admin=false){
    $price=($ceny*$ile);
    if($admin == false){
        $this->ceny['rent'] = $ceny['rent'];
        $this->ceny['pay'] = $ceny['pay'];
        $this->ceny['rec'] = $ceny['rec'];
    }
}//Function ends.
```

The illegal offset is in the following three lines:

```
$this->ceny['rent'] = $ceny['rent'];
$this->ceny['pay'] = $ceny['pay'];
$this->ceny['rec'] = $ceny['rec'];
```

Comment: what is `$this->ceny` and `$ceny`?

Comment: On which line does the error occur? What's the *exact* error message?

Comment: `$ceny` likely isn't an array, given you're multiplying by it on a previous line, therefore array indexing won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, You need to check if your offset is already set before you try to access it

```
private $ceny = array();

function _generate_users($ceny, $komu, $ile, $admin=false){
    $price=($ceny*$ile);
    if($admin == false){
        $this->ceny['rent'] = (isset($ceny['rent'])) ? $ceny['rent'] : '';
        $this->ceny['pay'] = (isset($ceny['pay'])) ? $ceny['pay'] : '';
        $this->ceny['rec'] = (isset($ceny['rec'])) ? $ceny['rec'] : '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the key exists before referencing it:

```
if ($admin == false) {
    foreach (array('rent', 'pay', 'rec') as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $ceny)) {
            $this->ceny[$key] = $ceny[$key];
        }
    }
}
```

However, you're also using `$ceny` as a numeric type above; what is the type of `$ceny`? I would suggest adding an `is_array` check, but it looks like you need to think about how you're using your variable.